# Express variables within raw string in bash

Tags: bash, shell, variables, concatenation

## Problem

I have a variable called `boiler`, and I want the variable `si1` to be expressed, and I am unsure of how to do this in a simple and minimal fashion.

```bash
boiler='#!/bin/bash
source ../../functions.sh
current="${si1}"
ready custom
title
breadcrumbs \""$current"\" \"Options\"
# END OF BOILER (DO NOT REMOVE ABOVE CODE OR MODIFY IT)
'
```

## ISSUE

The issue is that i want everything to be ignored withing this string (aka printed raw) except for the `${si1}` variable.

## EXPECTED OUTPUT

How could I concatenate the first part the variable and then the rest of the string while keeping it minimal and saving it back into the `boiler` variable?

Comment: I suspect the escaped double quotes on the "breadcrumbs" line are not needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delimit the string around `${si1}`.

```
boiler='#!/bin/bash
source ../../functions.sh
current='"${si1}"'
ready custom
title
breadcrumbs \""$current"\" \"Options\"
# END OF BOILER (DO NOT REMOVE ABOVE CODE OR MODIFY IT)
'
```

This is ordinary string concatenation. The strings delimited with `'` will be literal, while the string delimited with `"` will have the variable expanded.

[Difference between single and double quotes in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash)

Comment: And will it still be stored within the boiler variable?

Comment: Of course. This is just string concatenation. We use `'` around the strings we don't want variables replaced in, and `""` around the strings that should be.